# How can I add a backspace to a textView Android

Tags: android

I read the oracle escape sequence and realize that if I want to make a backspace in a textView I need to use "\b", the same way as we do for inserting a new line (/n). I've tried this line of code:

```
textView.setText("Hellos\bWorld");
```

Then, when I run the app, the textView shows this:

```
Hellos World
```

Intead of what I expected:

```
HelloWorld
```

I wish you can help me, how I can make a backspace within a textView. Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: give it a try with \\b

Comment: do you want to remove space from string?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to add a backspace character to a TextView? Even if it did work, why would you prefer `"Hellos\bWorld"` to `"HelloWorld"`? Understanding the context of the question might help us to provide an answer.

Comment: Karan i tried what tou told me, but it didn't work :(

Comment: Ben P, I am trying to use append instead of setText. That's why I need \b to delete some previous text and not to put the newer text next to the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest method remove space in string is `replace()` method. It accepts two arguments 1st what word/char you want to search in string and 2nd what you want to replace with.

```
String dummy = "Hellos World";
String newText = dummy.replace("s ","");
textView.setText(newText);

//output > HelloWorld
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro!! But what I am trying to do is delete the 's' letter

Comment: see my edited answer. I suggest you do not use `replace()` on complex strings.

Comment: I know what you mean bro, but imagine if there is another letter instead of 's'. That's why i am trying to use backspace. \b. But i don't know why this doesn't work

Comment: oh, I also tried with `\b` is doesn't delete character. You need to use `Substring()`

Comment: Bro and do you know why it doesn't work? I saw the following page and see that \b is used for backspace https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html

Answer (score 0):

```
String regex = "\\s*\\bis\\b\\s*";
        String str = "Hellos World";
        str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
        textView.setText(str);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer bro!! But what I am trying to do is delete the 's' letter

Comment: String regex = "\\s*\\bis\\b\\s*";
        String str = "Hello World";
        str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
        textView.setText(str);

Answer (score 0):

`\b` doesn't work the way you are thinking. Basically,

> \b allows you to perform a "whole words only". It matches the empty string at the beginning or end of a word.

So you can match `\bword\b` with `\b`. So to remove the character you want you either need to use substring or replace particular character.